# How do I create random (x,y) points having a Gaussian distribution?

Tags: r, random

I need to create a set of 100 random (x,y) points in R that are Gaussian. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `mvrnorm` function from MASS package

```
library(MASS)
Sigma <- matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2)  # Covariance Matrix
set.seed(1)  # For the example to be reproducible
Random_XY <- mvrnorm(n=100, c(0, 0), Sigma) # Random (x,y) from a Gaussian distr.
head(Random_XY) 

           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  2.3299984 -0.4196921
[2,] -0.2261965 -1.2474779
[3,]  2.3538800  1.7025069
[4,] -4.9527947 -1.8730622
[5,] -1.0148272 -0.4114252
[6,]  2.0557678  2.4378417
```

**EDIT**

Since a gaussian process has mean 0 and variance 1 and zero correlation, the correct answer should be:

```
mvrnorm(n=100, c(0, 0), diag(c(1,1)))
```

Where the vector of means is `c(0,0)` and a unitary covariance matrix `diag(c(1,1))`

As @Ben Bolker pointed out, the fastest way to go (using R Base function) is:

```
data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))
```

Comment: the OP might (they don't say) want *independent* normals, in which case they could more easily use `data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))`

Comment: Yes, @Ben Bolker you're right, if the OP wants to draw iid normal values then `data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100))` is the easiest way to go as you mention.

Comment: See also `rmvnorm()` in the **mvtnorm** package.

Comment: But even if they want independent normals, they might want different mean and sigmas :-).   The OP needs to learn how important it is in statistics work to state the problem as precisely as divinely (as oppposed to humanly) possible.